# after deploying rails app with apache and passenger, showing the page does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, passenger

i have deployed my rails app with apache2 and passenger. everything was going smoothly but after deploying it says the page you were looking for doesn't exist. my app name is opengrok

my apache cofiguration is in /etc/apache2/sites-avaibleable/opengrok

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
  DocumentRoot /var/www/opengrok/public
  <Directory /var/www/opengrok/public>
     # This relaxes Apache security settings.
     AllowOverride all
     # MultiViews must be turned off.
     Options -MultiViews
  </Directory>
```

whats the wrong then??

And the log says

```
 I, [2013-09-16T13:00:41.656536 #6184]  INFO -- : Started GET "/" for 107.109.10.218 at         2013-09-16 13:00:41 +0600
 F, [2013-09-16T13:00:41.663573 #6184] FATAL -- :
 ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `block in call'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:21:in `call'
 actionpack (4.0.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
 rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
 activesupport (4.0.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
 railties (4.0.0) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
 passenger (4.0.17) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in  `process_request'
 passenger (4.0.17) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:140:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
 passenger (4.0.17) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:108:in `main_loop'
 passenger (4.0.17) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:441:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

rake routes shows in my home directory is

```
Prefix Verb URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
           root GET /                              opengrok_pages#index
opengrok_pages_show GET /opengrok_pages/show(.:format) opengrok_pages#show
opengrok_pages_load GET /opengrok_pages/load(.:format) opengrok_pages#load
opengrok_pages_text GET /opengrok_pages/text(.:format) opengrok_pages#text
```

Comment: You should look into log files (apache's, passenger's, your app's).

Comment: i have updated my application log

Comment: Could you run `rake routes` into your app home directory? And what result it will produce

Comment: i did this but no use :(

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev i have updated my question with rake routes result

Comment: config.consider_all_requests_local to true in config/environments/production.rb, I could get the error message to display in production and see what the actual problem was. Obviously, change it back once you've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Can you please add "/" after public

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/opengrok/public/
```

Also directory root make it like.

```
<Directory /var/www/opengrok>
```

also put your rails environment

```
RailsEnv development
```

Below is my configuration file one of my project and this is working fine.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
        ServerName pacerpro-alpha.hoverstate.com
        ServerAlias alpha.pacerpro.com
       # ServerName 23.22.184.199
        DocumentRoot /data/www/pacerpro_1.5/MyECF-Web-Application/current/public/
        ErrorLog "logs/pacerpro-alpha.hoverstate.com-error.log"
        RailsEnv development
        <Directory /data/www/pacerpro_1.5/MyECF-Web-Application/current>
                AllowOverride all
                Options -MultiViews
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
```

Comment: I thought passenger recommendations (after installation `passenger-install-apache2-module`) was wrong, but adding `RailsEnv development` solved problem.