# Ruby on Rails Passenger bundle error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache2, passenger

I've got some problems with my Passenger on Apache. When I open my `localhost` location for ruby on rails with a page included when you create new project, there is a link: `About your application’s environment` and when I click it, I get error message form passenger

> Web application could not be started
>
> ....
>
> Could not find json-1.8.1 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

It advises me to run `bundle install` command, but when I do it, I get message:

```
Using rake 10.3.1
Using i18n 0.6.1
Using multi_json 1.9.2
Using activesupport 3.2.13
Using builder 3.0.4
Using activemodel 3.2.13
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using journey 1.0.4
Using rack 1.4.5
Using rack-cache 1.2
Using rack-test 0.6.2
Using hike 1.2.3
Using tilt 1.4.1
Using sprockets 2.2.2
Using actionpack 3.2.13
Using mime-types 1.25.1
Using polyglot 0.3.4
Using treetop 1.4.15
Using mail 2.5.4
Using actionmailer 3.2.13
Using arel 3.0.3
Using tzinfo 0.3.39
Using activerecord 3.2.13
Using activeresource 3.2.13
Using coffee-script-source 1.7.0
Using execjs 2.0.2
Using coffee-script 2.2.0
Using rack-ssl 1.3.4
Using json 1.8.1
Using rdoc 3.12.2
Using thor 0.19.1
Using railties 3.2.13
Using coffee-rails 3.2.2
Using jquery-rails 3.1.0
Using bundler 1.6.2
Using rails 3.2.13
Using sass 3.3.5
Using sass-rails 3.2.6
Using sqlite3 1.3.9
Using uglifier 2.5.0
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

My ruby version is (Sometimes it shows 1.9.3 version):

```
ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]
```

Rails:

```
Rails 3.2.13
```

Bundler

```
Bundler version 1.6.2
```

Also I've noticed some problems with my RVM. When I use `rvm default`, ruby versions changes to `2.1.1` and Rails `4.1.0`. Then after an hour or more it changes back to 1.9.3 and 3.2.13

Comment: try `rvm --default use 2.1.1` this will make ruby 2.1.1 your default ruby

Comment: editing my Virtualhost like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18827183/after-deploying-rails-app-with-apache-and-passenger-showing-the-page-does-not-e
helped me